# Problems with Circles and Lines on a Cartesian Plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, circles

**(a)** Find the equations of the two circles each of which touches both coordinate axes and passes through the point $(9,2)$.

**(b)** Find the coordinates of the second point of intersection of the two circles.

**(c)** Find an equation of the common chord in these two circles

Comment: Have you done any work on this problem so far?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to solve the simultaneous equations (9-a)^2+(2-b)^2=r^2, (n_x-a)^2+b^2=r^2 and a^2+(n_y-b)^2+r^2, where n_x and n_y are the respective x and y coordinates of where the circle touches the axes, but I have always ended up with very messy expressions, instead of a numerical solution, as requested.

Comment: Hint: When circles "touch" a line (say the axis), it does not just mean it intersects, it means the line (or axis) is also a tangent there.  So equation of a circle which touches both axes is $(x-a)^2+(y \pm a)^2 = a^2$ (why?)

Comment: (x-r)^2+(y-r)^2=r^2 therefore x^2+y^2+2xr+2yr+r^2=0 therefore substituting x=9 y=2, solving for r with the quadratic formula we obtain r=17, therefore equation of circle is (x-17)^2+(y-17)^2=17^2